How to refer to proc's own namespace inside an uplevel context in Tcl?
Inside a Tcl proc, I need to refer to variables both in the context of this proc as well as the level above because the file that is getting sourced uses variables there. So I tried writing something like:
proc source_file {file} {
    uplevel {source $file }
}

The problem with that is inside the 'uplevel' command, I can refer to variables at the top level, but now the local $file variable is not defined. I was hoping I can fix that by exposing the proc variable as file_up in the uplevel context, but that's not working either:
proc source_file {file} {
    upvar "file_up" $file
    uplevel {source $file_up }
}

source_file test.tcl
can't read "file_up": no such variable

What am I doing wrong?

Your upvar call isn't correct - it should be upvar 1 file file_up

Thanks for the response. But that's not the problem. When you don't specify a level, 1 is implied.

I see Glenn solved your issue anyway but I was referring to the order of the vars in your command.

You can use a different quoting mechanism so that the local variable is substituted and the value is passed back up to the caller:
proc source_file {file} {
    uplevel [list source $file]
}

upvar is not appropriate here: you're not passing a variable name to the proc.

Thanks for the help!
